# Sound Play / Stop / Pause

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-player

I'm developing a sound JavaScript library. I can play sound with below code.

```
var soundPlayer = null;

function playSound(){

soundPlayer = new Audio(soundName).play();

}
```

How can I stop and pause this audio? When I try like this:

```
soundPlayer.pause();
```

Or

```
soundPlayer.stop();
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: soundPlayer.stop is not a function
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you change that:

```
soundPlayer = new Audio(soundName).play();
```

To that:

```
soundPlayer = new Audio(soundName);
soundPlayer.play();
```

Your pause will be working. The problem is that you assigned "play" function to soundPlayer. SoundPlayer isnt an Audio object now.

Instead of stop() use:

```
soundPlayer.pause();
soundPlayer.currentTime = 0;
```

It works the same I guess.

Comment: Yes. these two functions will be working if you change what I mentioned. Your soundPlayer is a function "play" now, not an Audio object. That is why stop and pause dont work.

Comment: I changed my code with your code. Now, .pause() function is working. Thanks! But stop() function isn't working. How i do that?

Comment: Try soundPlayer.pause();
soundPlayer.currentTime = 0;

Comment: There is no function like stop()? ``soundPlayer.currentTime = 0`` works though.